# Make PopupMenu from bottom?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a PopupMenu that appears from the bottom of the screen, specifically when I press the back button I want the menu to appear from roughly the area where the back button is. However, I can't figure out a way to have the PopupMenu expand from the bottom of the screen

Here is my code so far:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(this, findViewById(R.id.view_pager), Gravity.BOTTOM);
    menu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.backpressedmenu, menu.getMenu());
    menu.show();
}
```

This just shows the menu above the top of the view_pager view, and I can't manage to make the menu appear at the bottom of the view_pager view.

I was able to find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516247/how-change-position-of-popup-menu-on-android-overflow-button) however it is decently out-of-date. I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644030/popup-menu-at-bottom-of-a-view), but the answers did not help and it's also quite an old question.

Comment: How about taking a transparent view at the Bottom of screen and show pop up on this view . Keep views height as minimum as possible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need bottom sheet not `PopupMenu`.

Do check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410280/how-to-get-popup-menu-from-bottom-of-screen) and [this article](https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/android-bottom-sheet-5b64ddb3c02d).